# Centos: fn start : mounting none on /sys/kernel/security failed: Permission denied

Tags: linux, docker, fn

After installing fn from https://github.com/fnproject/fn

I run "`fn start`" as `root`

I get the following error

```
[root@localhost my-docker-app]# fn start
sh: overlay: unknown operand
mount: mounting none on /sys/kernel/security failed: Permission denied
Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
time="2017-10-07T09:42:36Z" level=error msg="couldn't ping db" error="unable to open database file" url=/app/data/fn.db
time="2017-10-07T09:42:36Z" level=fatal msg="Error initializing datastore." error="unable to open database file"
2017/10/07 11:42:37 error: proce

ssed finished with error exit status 1
```

any help?

Centos version and fn version

```
[root@localhost my-docker-app]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

[root@localhost my-docker-app]# fn version
Client version: 0.4.7
ERROR: Get http://localhost:8080/version: dial tcp [::1]:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
[root@localhost my-docker-app]#
```

Comment: Please add output of `docker version` to your question and also output of `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Lalwani Attached the version.

Comment: @jww : fn is a serverless platform for development of function. This space was suggested by "fn team" itself as the right place where to post issues.

Comment: The fn team doesn't get to decide what is on-topic or off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Disable Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux), Its caused due to this.

Issue the below command as root for temporaryly disable selinux

$ setenforce 0

OR

- vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
- Change the value of SELINUX as below
- SELINUX=disabled
- reboot